# Can an application be configured to launch with a specific argument by default?

Tags: macos, mac

I want Chrome to start with the argument `--enable-extension-timeline-api`, required by the [speedtracer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) extension.  I know I can do it manually with `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --enable-extension-timeline-api`, but I'd like to make it the default.

For now it's working with an ugly hack -- I moved the actual "Google Chrome" executable aside and replaced it with a shell script that adds the option I need.  But there must be a better way.  Or at least a more mac-y way.

Comment: Should I have posted this to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the *Speed tracer bootstrap application* as per instructions on the [getting started page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/get-started.html).

A more Mac-y way isn't possible, unless it's built into the application.